# OpenDatabaseForm that behaves like OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I am using an embedded database (SQLite) for my program, so when a user wants to work from an existing database entry, they can use a simple winforms UI to see which files are in the database, select one and continue with the program.

I've made the UI, but need the form to exhibit behaviour that's just like OpenFileDialog w.r.t. the following:

```
if(openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      file = openFileDialog.FileName;
```

so it should look something like the following:

```
OpenDatabaseDialog odd = new OpenDatabaseDialog();
odd.Show();
if(odd.IsOK)
      file = odd.FileName;
```

I have already tried to expose some properties in my OpenDatabaseDialog, IsOk (a bool that is true if form successfully got a filename from user) and FileName (a string which should hold the actual file name string).

The problem is, the program doesn't wait for OpenDatabaseDialog to actually execute, it just skips it the selection structure, which of course fails as the user has had no time to input anything.

Another method I was thinking of to accomplish this is just extending the OpenFileDialog class and making its behaviour work to my liking, but this seems very complicated to do.

Any suggestions on a good way to do this?

Comment: You are calling Show, instead you should call ShowDialog if you want your form to behave as a modal dialog box.

Comment: Also there is no need to have a IsOK property. Just set your button property DialogResult to DialogResult.OK. In the button event handler check if you have a file and, if not, change the form DialogResult property to DialogResult.None. This will allow you use the same code example for the OpenFileDialog

Comment: Perfect, thanks man. I didn't realize that you could call the form as a modal dialog box, I thought you had to implement that behaviour or something. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form` controls have a `DialogResult` property, the value of which is returned from the `ShowDialog` method. So all you have to do is add an `Ok` button to your dialog form, and add code to set the `DialogResult` (and to close the form) behind that button.

For example:

```
public partial class OpenDatabaseDialog : Form
{
    public OpenDatabaseDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set any properties necessary that indicate the user's selections

        // User clicked 'Ok' so set our result (which will also close the form)
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Then, in your main form's code, you can capture the result as you would any other dialog, by calling `ShowDialog` and capturing the return value.

Main Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var openDbDialog = new OpenDatabaseDialog();

        // Show the form as a dialog and capture the result
        if (openDbDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked 'Ok' to close the dialog");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You closed the dialog some other way");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to call this.Close if you set the form's DialogResult property. It will be closed automatically when you exit the event handler (unless you set the special DialogResult.None)

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I did not realize that! updated answer.